# HWIOAuthBundle permitting the user to add a password before submitting the data retrieved from facebook

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

there! I have just integrated HWIOAuthBundle with my Symfony2 application, but I would like to permit the user to enter a password, which he will use for my website login beside the email that will be retrieved from facebook before submitting the form that persists the data(email from facebook and password entered by the user) to my database. I would like to let the user submit this form and not do it automatically as it is done now,,Is there a class in the bundle that I could modify or override to achieve this? I hope I made myself clear enough,,Thanks!!